# Populate Treeview with directory from Combobox.Text

Tags: vb.net, combobox, treeview

I have a combobox from which I select folder names. This folders are searched in my D:\ and when they are found a folder named "Versions" in It has to be found too. Then this "Versions" subfolder needs to be populated with all subfolders on a Treeview. Any ideas on how I could do this, I really bumped into this one ?!? My code so far (no errors, but nothing happens):

EDITED CODE (still not working):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

 Dim folder1 As String() = Directory.GetDirectories("D:\", MyCombo.Text, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each folder1 As String In MyDirectory
        Dim SubDirectories As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder1, "*Versions*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        For Each subfolder In SubDirectories
            PopulateFolder(subfolder) 
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFolder(folder As String)

     tv1.Nodes(0).Text = folder
     tv1.Nodes(0).ImageIndex = 1
     Dim DirSep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
     Dim thisFolder As String
     Dim tn As TreeNode

     For Each d As String In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folder)
            ' split the path to get the last segment
            Dim split = d.Split(DirSep)
            thisFolder = split(split.Length - 1)
            tn = New TreeNode(thisFolder, 1, 1)
            tv1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(tn)
            PopulateFiles(tn, d)
      Next
      PopulateFiles(tv1.Nodes(0), folder)
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFiles(tn As TreeNode, folder As String)

   For Each f As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.*")
       ' Path will extract the name:
       tn.Nodes.Add("", Path.GetFileName(f), 0)
   Next
End Sub
```

HERE IS A SCREENSHOT AND ANOTHER EXPLANATION OF WHAT I NEED:

[image]

So, 1st code must search for folder named "Microsoft" as combobox item shows. Then, within this folder another search must occur for folder named "Versions". And finally, populate all underlying subfolders/files from "Versions". NO folders before or in same level as "Versions" on Treeview ! In this case my path to "Versions" is "D:\MyDocuments\Programmes\Microsoft\Versions\" - paths of searches are different, but all are in "D:\" directory and all contain "Versions" folder.

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance !!

Comment: This is a debugging problem.  What's the value of MyCombo.Text when the code runs?

Comment: @LarsTech, MyCombo.Text value is "Microsoft" - so It should search for Microsoft folder in D:\. Search for path is O.K. as I see It in debugger, It stucks at "For each f as FileInfo".

Comment: Code works as posted otherwise.

Comment: @LarsTech not for me. What could be wrong in my case ?

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: @Plutonix,@LarsTech, I don't know why but nothing happens for me. I tested in a new project too. I have to try It at home, maybe something is blocking my code here at office.

Comment: make sure *all* your assumptions about the data are true

Comment: @Plutonix, I think i figured out my problem, thanks for pointing me to It.  "Dim fInfo() As FileInfo = dInfo.GetFiles" needs to be changed - It shows me ony files from directory, but in this particular folder (Microsoft) I have only folders, without files. How could I change that to show files & folders (If they exist) ?

Comment: Are you trying to organize files under a parent node representing the folder?  Or lump all files from various folders together?

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm trying to populate all folders and subfolders under parent node, but show files under parent node if they exist too.

Answer (score 1):

This will populate a `Treeview` with folders and files organized as they are on disk... But wait there's more:

> what I need to display is just a folder/file name,

*In re* Edit: The code remains much the same as the first two versions, just some helpers have been broken out to "find" the starting point and specific child folders:

```
Private Function FindVersionsFolder(startFolder As String) As String
    ' find a folder named "Versions" to be used as the start point
    ' note: can return "" when not found
    Dim curPath As String = Path.Combine(startFolder, "Versions")
    Dim temp As String = ""

    If Directory.Exists(curPath) Then
        Return curPath
    Else
        For Each d As String In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(startFolder)
            temp = FindVersionsFolder(d)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(temp) = False Then Return temp
        Next
    End If
    Return ""

End Function

Private Sub PopulateFolder(folder As String, parentNode As TreeNode,
                           Optional pattern As String = "*")
    ' create node for current folder, 
    '   add child folders
    '   add files contained
    Dim thisFolder As String
    Dim tn As TreeNode

    For Each d As String In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folder, pattern)
        thisFolder = GetLastFolder(d)

        tn = New TreeNode(thisFolder, 1, 1)
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(tn)

        ' recurse to add child folders
        PopulateFolder(d, tn)
        ' populate files in this folder
        PopulateFiles(tn, d)
    Next
    ' if desired the files in base "VERSIONS" folder
    'PopulateFiles(tv1.Nodes(0), folder)
End Sub

Private Function GetLastFolder(fullPath As String) As String
    ' trim to the last folder segment
    Dim DirSep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
    Dim split = fullPath.Split(DirSep)
    Return split(split.Length - 1)
End Function

Private Sub PopulateFiles(tn As TreeNode, folder As String)
    ' add all files for a folder
    For Each f As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.*")
        tn.Nodes.Add("", Path.GetFileName(f), 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
    Dim startFolder = "C:\Temp\Microsoft"
    ' modify root node
    tv1.TopNode.Text = GetLastFolder(startFolder)
    tv1.TopNode.ImageIndex = 1

    ' find the starting point
    startFolder = FindVersionsFolder(startFolder)

    ' populate TV from that point
    PopulateFolder(startFolder, tv1.Nodes(0), "Ver*")
```

It adds the files for the starting folder after the folder (like Explorer).  I am not sure why you are using `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()) and getting a bunch of`FileInfo`objects if you just want the name.  This uses`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`which is a little more efficient than`GetFiles()`.

My test starting point has some obstacles and folders/file to be excluded:

[image]

The result seems to be what you want.  It also adds an icon so you can tell Files from Folders:

[image][image]

---

To get the associated icon for each file type, see **[Show folder icon in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35076625/1070452)**.  Don't let the `ListView` part throw you - both controls use an ImageList for images.

Comment: thanks, I will test this tommorow. Although what I need to display is just a folder/file name, excluding It's path like you provided in sample. And I still need part of code for searching my "Microsoft" folder...But I guess that I can change that...Looks very nice with icons -one question here - can I use icons for files like Explorer does ? (from .dll if im not mistaken)

Comment: I tested your code but I'ts not working for me, I get error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values." in line "tv1.Nodes(0).Text = folder". Take a look at my edited question please, you'll see another explanation under image I provided.